# Nuxt.js 3 application with Mongoose/MongoDB not starting in production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt.js 3 (rc4) application running well on the dev server, but the production build crashes on start. I'm using Mongoose to connect to a Mongo DB and the issue seems to be there, particularly with the `whatwg-url` package used by Mongoose or one of its dependencies.

After running in debug mode I can see that `whatwg_url_1.URL` is `undefined` and it should be a class.

I'm using the latest versions of Nuxt (3.0.0-rc.4) and Mongoose (6.4.0).

Here's the output:

```
/var/app/.output/server/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:74
class URLWithoutHost extends whatwg_url_1.URL {
                                          ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/.output/server/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:74:43)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/.output/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js:6:41)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
```

EDIT:
There seems to be an incompatibility between Mongoose/MongoDB and another library, `google-auth-library`. Removing one or the other makes it run.
[Related issue report](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/custom-google-authentication-potential-bug/154946)

On build it warns the following:

```
 WARN  Multiple major versions of package webidl-conversions are being externalized. Picking latest version.                                                         16:06:10  
  - .../node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/webidl-conversions@3.0.1
  - .../node_modules/webidl-conversions@7.0.0
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@flanker72/nuxt3-complex-solutions-database-integration-8df941f0fb82 this helped me in setup

Comment: @AdarshMadrecha this was not the question. The question was about resolving conflicting npm package, not hwo to do a basic mongoose Nuxt setup...

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue and also haven't found a solution yet, as you mentioned, it is a conflict with libraries that use an npm package called `whatwg-url` like `google-auth-library` or in my case `@nuxtjs/supabase`

This only happens when in production mode, but when using `nuxi dev` everything runs smoothly. I'm wondering if there are some build configurations that can be added to solve this issue

The dependency graph looks like this:

```
dependencies:
mongoose 6.5.3
└─┬ mongodb 4.8.1
  └─┬ mongodb-connection-string-url 2.5.3
    └── whatwg-url 11.0.0

devDependencies:
@nuxtjs/supabase 0.1.23
└─┬ @supabase/supabase-js 1.35.6
  ├─┬ @supabase/functions-js 1.3.4
  │ └─┬ cross-fetch 3.1.5
  │   └─┬ node-fetch 2.6.7
  │     └── whatwg-url 5.0.0
  ├─┬ @supabase/gotrue-js 1.22.22
  │ └─┬ cross-fetch 3.1.5
  │   └─┬ node-fetch 2.6.7
  │     └── whatwg-url 5.0.0
  ├─┬ @supabase/postgrest-js 0.37.4
  │ └─┬ cross-fetch 3.1.5
  │   └─┬ node-fetch 2.6.7
  │     └── whatwg-url 5.0.0
  └─┬ @supabase/storage-js 1.7.3
    └─┬ cross-fetch 3.1.5
      └─┬ node-fetch 2.6.7
        └── whatwg-url 5.0.0
nuxt 3.0.0-rc.8
└─┬ nitropack 0.4.24
  └─┬ @vercel/nft 0.21.0
    └─┬ @mapbox/node-pre-gyp 1.0.9
      └─┬ node-fetch 2.6.7
        └── whatwg-url 5.0.0
```

Comment: Yes, we need to find a solution wherein we can build nuxt using respective deep dependency version. For me too, the issue only arrise in Build not in dev.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue with Nuxt3, @Khaled's post is very helpful. In my case this is caused by `whatwg-url` conflict in `node-fetch` and `mongodb`, very similar if not identical to what @Khaled's has encountered. Simply forcing the dependency version seems to work for me.

So in your `package.json`, add:

```
"overrides":{ "whatwg-url": "11.0.0"   }
```

Then to be safe, remove `node_modules` directory and `yarn.lock` or `package.lock.json`, reinstall packages, run something like `yarn why whatwg-url` and see if it's using the updated version.

Comment: Adding override doesn't help as the library functionality has changed drastically over the major versions. So, using overrides causes another issue.

Comment: @Adarsh Madrecha, you are correct, this is just a patch that trade one problem for another, depending on the application, this might/might not be a viable soliton.